# How to get backup of the CouchDB locally in android device?

Tags: android, couchdb

I am not much familiar in CouchDB. I have used CouchDB to store the documents (images, audio & video files) which user has uploaded from Android app. Those documents were stored locally in his mobile not in server. We provide an option to update the software with new couchDB which is hold HTML and some uploaded files. Now my problem is while updating the app, I need to get backup of old CouchDB and store it any place. After update completed copy the documents from old to new then delete the backup of couchDB.

Please anyone guide me to achieve this. Is any other possible to achieve without getting backup?